# Flutter google map myLocation button iOS style

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I'm using google_maps_flutter package in my app, and default myLocation style is different between iOS and Android platform.

I prefer the iOS style, which button is on the bottom right corner, and round shape.
But in Android is totally different, rectangle and placed on the top right corner.

Is it any possible to change the style of button from Android to iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating your custom button instead. Set `myLocationButtonEnabled` to `false` and create a `FloatingActionButton` in `Google Maps` widget.

```
GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        initialCameraPosition: _yourLocation,
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        }, ),
        myLocationEnabled: true,
       myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            foregroundColor: Colors.grey,
            elevation: 5,
            onPressed: () => _getCurrentLocation(),
            child: Icon(Icons.my_location)),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Then implement custom `_getCurrentLocation()` method using the [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location/example)  or  [geolocator](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator)  package.

Comment: I've tried this before.The problem is : I need the mylocation blue circle showing, so myLocationButtonEnable must be true. But if I use both _getCurrentLocation &  myLocationButtonEnabled , it's so delay when I press button. So I'm wondering if I can change the mylocation button style directly to fix this problem. But still thank for your answer !